# Firebase Not working in desktop app while it's working in (Web Serve & Build)

Tags: typescript, firebase, webpack, electron, angularfire

**Version info**
Angular: 16, Firebase: 9.23.0, AngularFire: 7.6.1

I have added Realtime firebase in this repo:
https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/

Or I can say added this example into the electron JS repo
https://github.com/bezkoder/angular-16-firebase-crud

Combined Repo Firebase into electron: https://github.com/anoop-mobi/electronTestFirebase (add APIs in firebase_enviourment please)

Getting Error is
[image]

And in the web
[image]

Actual Output is
throwing an error in electron JS application

@firebase/auth: Auth (9.23.0): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition
y @ main.8b5b2e5c35662f68.js:1
main.8b5b2e5c35662f68.js:1 [2023-08-12T11:34:03.298Z] @firebase/auth: Auth (9.23.0): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition
y @ main.8b5b2e5c35662f68.js:1
main.8b5b2e5c35662f68.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition
Error: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition

I was looking for to enable firebase in the desktop application
[image]